# click @ checkbox is done but not registered

Tags: selenium

I`m relatively new to Selenium and trying to create some test cases with the Selenium IDE.

I just selected a checkbox with XPath with the following command `xpath=//input[starts-with(@id,'003g')]`.

After the checkbox is selected, I click another button to add the value from the checkbox.
But nothing happens. The application always tells me that no record is selected... If I push the play button I can see IT IS selected.

What to do?

Thank you guys!

edit:
At first... Thanks for your help!

I don`t think, the problem is caused due the fact that the element is not present. I can see that Selenium selects the according data record (checkbox)

Here is some code. I hope it will help! In fact I am new to this whole webstuff and have no clue about web techniques.

```
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-checkbox x-grid3-cell-first
"tabindex="0" style="width:18px;">
<div id="003g0000006ElPO_checkbox" class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-checkbox">
<input id="003g0000006ElPO" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ids" title="<a
href="/003g0000006ElPO">
<span>JeanneSeleniumOne</span></a>" value="003g0000006ElPO">
```

Comment: Can you post the html code? That will give us more context to what is supposed to be happening. For example, it's possible that your website uses javascript events to dynamically update when you tick the checkbox, but these events are not being fired by Selenium; but we can't really be sure unless we see some html.

Answer (score 0):

There's too little information to help, but a wild-guess would be the element wasn't ready to be clicked i.e. you should wait for some time before clicking.

I just posted a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063377/wait-for-an-element-using-selenium-webdriver/18070700#180707000)