# How to click the upload button in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunittestadapter

May I know, how to find the element for upload button and proceed it with a mouse click by the following HTML code below:

```
<div class="uploadImage-wrap">
      <!-- Comment Title -->
      <div class="uploadImageTitle-wrap">
          <h2>Upload Files</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="uploadImage-containerSEC-2">

             <div id="dropzoneplaceSEC-2" class="dz-message">

                <div class="needsclick">
                <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i></br>
                Drop files here to upload.<br> or browse for a file

              </div>        
            </div>
           <input name="userFileName" type="hidden" value=""  id="userFileNameSEC-2">
           <input name="issueKey" type="hidden" value=""  id="issueKeySEC-2">
          <a href="#"><button type="button" id="uploadImageButtonSEC-2" class="btn blue changeBtn display-none" style='margin-left:40%;' onclick="addAttachmentForIssue(this)">Upload</button></a>

     </div>
</div><br/>
```

Comment: It has an `id`. What exactly is problem?

Comment: is say element not found when i wrote the this code
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropzoneplaceSEC-2"));
 js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Element);
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("uploadImageButtonSEC-2")).Click();

Comment: Try adding some wait https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374382/how-to-wait-for-element-to-load-in-selenium-webdriver/40397653

Comment: This button has class `display-none`, probably it is invisible. Are you sure that is the button you really want to click?

Comment: driver.FindElement works for visible items only meaning they should be visible and not covered by other elements

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov yup i wanna click the button as once i uploaded the image the upload button only appear. how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your comment:

> yup i wanna click the button as once i uploaded the image the upload
>   button only appear. how can i do that?

you have to use `WebDriverWait` to wait until element will be clickable:

```
// after you have uploaded an image
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var clickableElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Id("uploadImageButtonSEC-2")));
clickableElement.click();
```

this will wait at least 1 minute until element will be clickable and only then clicks on it.

Note: if your id is generic, you can use `xPath` to locate it:

```
//button[starts-with(@id, 'uploadImageButton')]
```

and code:

```
// after you have uploaded an image
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var clickableElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.Xpath("//button[starts-with(@id, 'uploadImageButton')]")));
clickableElement.click();
```