# How to Handle Popup in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog, selenium-chromedriver, bootstrap-modal

I tried everything from alerts to multiple window handlers but not able to get rid of the popup come when we load below site on initial stage.

https://www.build.com/

Can you please help me on this to just get to above URL and handle the pop up, want to close it straight away.

Thanks
Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is within a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) so to locate/click on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

### Solution

You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.close.js-modal-close. > span.close-icon"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='close js-modal-close ']/span[@class='close-icon']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank You, But I tried the simple explicit wait and cllick on close button to achieve the same.

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati Inducing _WebDriverWait_ for `element_to_be_clickable()` is part of the best practices while invoking `click()`. You can't avoid it when dealing with Javascript based elements.

Answer (score 1):

The pop up you are referring to is not exactly a "Pop Up" window. Its just an element loading in the same page. So, wait till that element appears in the page and click the close button.

```
# in Java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='close-icon']")).click();

# or in JavaScript
document.querySelector('.close-icon').click();
```

To wait for any particular element, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18074070/7964299)

Comment: Thank You, I used the same to close that window.